# magento CE v1.6 toplinks in static block

Tags: magento

I would like to have the topLinks within Magento CE 1.6 displayed within a static block. This is due to the fact that my site is running four different stores [multi-store - different domains] and need to have topLinks on only two stores, whilst using one template.

I did try to convert the php call [getChildHtml('topLinks'); ?>] into a block tag within the static block but was not successful. Have looked in depth at the xml for the template_links [made from varied xmls] but could not come to terms as how to just make a {{block}} within the static block to display the topLinks.

The call for the static block is in place, just need help achieving the topLinks within.

Any help will be appreciated.

With best regards

Fab

---

A fine tune of my question:

Basically I need to amend the page.xml

from

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

to

```
<layout>
<static_block_top_links>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>topLinks</name>
        </action>
        <block type="cms/block" before="-" name="some_name" as="topLinks">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <name>some_static_block</name>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</static_block_top_links>

<STORE_store>
    <update handle="static_block_top_links" />
</STORE_store>

<STORE_law>
    <update handle="static_block_top_links" />
</STORE_law>
```

Comment: Basically I am trying to convert the php call into a block{{ but was not successful. Have looked around the xml files but cannot refer to the templates_link. The call for the static block is in place already

Comment: If you edit your question to put those things in, I can remove the -1.

Comment: Thanks for updating the score of the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello for anyone of you having a magento CE 1.6+ multi-store multi-domain and would like to remove the topLinks in general for certain stores, this is the correct method.

Create a local.xml in your app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/layout/

Your local.xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<STORE_mystore1>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>topLinks</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</STORE_mystore1>

<STORE_mystore2>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>topLinks</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</STORE_mystore2>   
</layout>
```

Replace the mystore1 and mystore2 with the code under Store View [Admin -> Manage Stores -> Store View Name -> Code]

Make sure that you encode the layout.xml in UTF-8

Upload the layout.xml in the app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/layout/ folder.

Refresh the cache.

I would like to thank Daniel Sloof and Robert Popovic for their input.

Answer (score 1):

Use local.xml to implement your changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <!-- Unset original toplinks block -->
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>topLinks</name>
            </action>

            <!-- Add static block in place with same alias -->
            <block type="cms/block" before="-" name="some_name" as="topLinks">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <name>some_static_block</name>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Please note that 'some_name' can be anything except for 'top.links', as that would cause several things in core XML files to try and perform actions on your cms block.

In response to your edit, you can easily do it for only some stores like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <static_block_top_links>
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>topLinks</name>
            </action>
            <block type="cms/block" before="-" name="some_name" as="topLinks">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <name>some_static_block</name>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </static_block_top_links>

    <STORE_myfirststore>
        <update handle="static_block_top_links" />
    </STORE_myfirststore>

    <STORE_mysecondstore>
        <update handle="static_block_top_links" />
    </STORE_mysecondstore>
</layout>
```

Comment: With this method, can I set the static block for a particular store and not in the other. Basically my site is made of four different stores and I would not like to have two stores showing the topLinks, still though keep to the same template. Regs

Comment: @FabianBorg: Then please update your answer to reflect that too ;) Anyway this method can be used for that too. Instead of 'default' handle, use 'STORE_yourstorecode'.

Comment: @FabianBorg: See modified answer.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your guidance. From my understanding of your help [myself being a novice ;)] your method would keep to just the xml by hiding the toplinks in general and activate such for the two sites. Also the header.phtml, shall I keep the original [<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>] and remove the static block call. Regs

Comment: @FabianBorg: You don't need to make any changes to the template so you can revert any changes you made. Instead of hiding it simply removes the block and adds a static block in place with the same alias. Your other assumpions are correct.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your help. Please see the edit of my question. I have page.xml that has the top.links reference. Shall I keep to having a static block or shall I keep to just xml and have page.xml top.links hidden and displayed for just the two stores named store and law. Regs

Comment: @FabianBorg: I said nothing about amending/modifying page.xml... Use 'local.xml' file in layout folder inside your theme.

Comment: Daniel, thanks again for your help. I have no local.xml in the layout folder but page.xml

Comment: @FabianBorg: Then create it ;)

Comment: Ok, I will try and do it. Layout folder only contains the following catalog.xml, catalogsearch.xml, checkout.xml, newsletter.xml, page.xml & sendfriend.xml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11521/discussion-between-fabian-borg-and-daniel-sloof)